# Simulator/device does not sync with iCloud

Tags: ios, synchronization, icloud

From time to time I'm getting errors that my iOS 8 device or simulator will sometimes not sync with iCloud (Drive). The following message appears (multiple times) in the output log:

> CoreData: iCloud: Error: failed to receive initial sync notification
>   call back in 90 seconds

Only reinstalling the app helps.
Has anyone experienced the same issue or got some information about this?

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing this too. This happens on iOS 8 simulator but not iOS 7 simulator. Device seems to have no problem and regularly syncs after a set interval which is good to see.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen that error (today) on an iPad running iOS 8. I fixed it by performing a reset (hold power and home/sleep buttons until the Apple logo appears). After that when I reran my app it synced immediately.

For the simulator it may be sufficient just to quit the simulator and relaunch. However, I have seen cases where restarting the computer was required.

I'm not sure what the cause of the issue is but hopefully the above help.

Comment: Thanks! Was having the same issue on my iPad today! Saved me some time... :)

Comment: I managed to get a re-sync in the simulator by going to settings -> my apple id account (first option) -> iCloud, and then disabling and re-enabling the "iCloud Drive" option.

Comment: That worked forever, disabling iCloud Drive and then enabling. However, it looks like it does not work anymore. This seems totally unpredictable now.